# Using Woodstox with Spring-WS

Tags: xml, spring-ws, jaxb2, woodstox

When Spring-WS is used with JAXB for marshalling & unmarshalling, which streaming implementation is used internally?

```
response = (AResponse) webSvcTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
```

Read through SO queries and found that Woodstox is faster than JAXB. However, as I use Spring-WS, Spring literally takes care of the entire stuff that happens during marshalling and unmarshalling.

Question is how do I force Spring-WS to use Woodstox streaming API ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When Spring-WS is used with JAXB for marshalling & unmarshalling, which streaming implementation is used internally?

That depends on which `WebServiceMessageFactory` you've enabled. By default Spring-WS uses SAAJ (i.e. `SaajSoapMessageFactory`), which is based on DOM, and does not do any streaming at all as the entire XML structure is stored in memory. You can switch from SAAJ to Axiom (i.e. `AxiomSoapMessageFactory`), which does do StAX-based streaming. See [the reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/common.html#message-factories).

> Read through SO queries and found that Woodstox is faster than JAXB.

That really depends on the context: size of the messages, hardware you're running on, etc. From personal experience, I've found that streaming is not significantly faster for 'small' to 'medium' sized SOAP messages.

Also, you are comparing apples with oranges here: Woodstox is a StAX implementation, an XML parser. JAXB is a marshaling library, which builds Java objects from XML using parsers like StAX (but also SAX, and DOM).

> However, as I use Spring-WS, Spring literally takes care of the entire stuff that happens during marshalling and unmarshalling.

Isn't it great? ;)

> Question is how do I force Spring-WS to use Woodstox streaming API ?

Simply putting Woodstox on the class path should be enough, Spring-WS will pick it up automatically. You would have to switch to Axiom (see above) though, before you can notice any difference. And even then I would wager that the performance difference is not that big.

Comment: Thanks Arjen. I understand the first part of the answer clearly that I shouldnt be comparing JAXB and Woodstox. Have a naive question though- However, does adding Woodstox to the classpath make JAXB to use Woodstox as the parser instead of Stax or SAX or DOM and does it make sense to do so from a performance perspective? I have really big SOAP responses (in MBs) to process and I use JAXB from Java Object <-> XML conversion.

Comment: First off: Woodstox is a StAX implementation. Therefore, "use Woodstox as the parsers instead of Stax" does not make any sense. Adding Woodstox to the class path will make Java use that as its StAX implementation instead of the slower default implementation. And like I said above: if you switch to Axiom, you will effectively use StAX/Woodstox for JAXB marshaling. Whether that gives better performance can't be stated upfront. The only thing you can do is measure the performance of your web service before and after the switch to Axiom & Woodstox.

Comment: Thanks Arjen..that clarifies all the queries I had. Appreciate your help..I will post my findings on the performance difference (if any)